# Google Places API types functionality..

Tags: google-places-api

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=true"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                var input = document.getElementById('location');
                var options = {                    
                    types: ["locality"]
                };

                autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
            });
        </script>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Location: <input type="text" id="location" style="width:400px;" /></div>               
    </body>
</html>
```

There is my code to generate my autocomplete location text input. Google's list of supported types (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/supported_types.html) shows "locality" as being the type to use when I do not wish for everything to come back in the result(businesses, etc). I am getting no results.

Basically, what I would like to achieve is to search for a city (IE: Toronto) And only see results like: "Toronto, ON, Canada". Perhaps I am confused on how I implement this API.

Thank you very much for your replies!

Comment: i don't think locality is a type///

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the option you are looking for according to the docs is "geocode" ( http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#AutocompleteOptions ):

```
var options = {                    
    types: ["geocode"]
};
```

Comment: Just went to the link you posted, and while locality is listed in the types, if you look at this link ( http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html#place_types ) , you'll see it only actually lists two (seems weird that they would have a link to a list of types and then right below it say only 2 types work, but that looks like what it is) - so either way, geocode looks like the option you want.

Comment: Geocode is almost the result I am looking for. Unfortunately, it still lists street names. Ex: If I search for "London, UK", "London Street, SomeCity, SomeCountry" will show up as a result.  

Where can I find explanations of these types? I don't see anything in Google's docs.

Comment: Landmarks will return with geocode as well... airports for example.

Comment: Ah I see now though via your link that only 2 types can be used with the AutoComplete. So I suppose geocode will have to suffice. Thanks for the reply Brad.

Comment: Daveomania_x, you should accept this as the answer if that's the case.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

you can also use the country restriction

example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() 
    {
      var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
      var options = {
          types: ['(cities)'],
          componentRestrictions: {country: "ca"}
      };

      autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Anything you want!">
```

now you can easily add a dropdown with a selection of cities and re-filter the cities, when onchange of the dropdown occurs :)

Answer (score 0):

Try, check out the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vnFqP/):

```
 var options = {                    
      types: ['geocode']
 };
```

> types, which can be either **establishment** or **geocode**, representing
>   businesses or addresses, respectively. If types is not specified, both
>   types are returned.

Answer (score 0):

If the user types `Tor` in the input field and the output you want is `Toronto, ON, Canada` then you should use `types=(regions)`, with the brackets.

I don't know if the option was present when the question was asked, but it is available now.

Sample Request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Tor&key=<YOUR_API_KEY_HERE>&types=(regions)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this
 `types: ['geocode' || 'establishment' || 'address']`

Comment: The doc say "The exception is that you can safely mix the geocode and establishment types, but note that this will have the same effect as specifying no type" (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_types)