# Google Map API V3 Weighted Search Results

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I was wondering if anyone knows if it possible to weight search results based on country or other variables?

Basically, what I'm looking to do is have user enter a street address but search Canada before searching the rest of the world.

The issue that I am encountering is users are not inputting their full address (inc. Province and Country) and the map is defaulting to addresses outside of Canada.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this even possible?

Yes! See [Component Filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ComponentFiltering).

Comment: Thank you! You pointed me in the right direction... This article helped as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189126/google-places-api-types-functionality