# filtering by type results from Google Places API autocomplete

Tags: android, google-maps, autocomplete

I would like to filter autocomplete results by ones which type includes geocode. 
example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/jsonsensor=false&key=API_KEY&input=osij
```

I dont want adresses and such which dont possess geocode type.

I already tried adding:

```
"&type=geocode"
```

but results dont change. Im making an android app, so this doesnt help me [Google Places API types functionality..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189126/google-places-api-types-functionality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected parameter is `types`, not `type`

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?sensor=false&input=osij&types=geocode&key=API_KEY
```

Comment: Thanks. It's always the simplest things. Although I thout that if something is geocode taged it also has viwport tag in google places api under details. If you know how to filter for those places I would be grateful.

Comment: Sorry, there is no way to filter these places via the request.